# Is it possible to create / alter PDF's inside the Server application (NodeJS on Swisscom Application Cloud)?

Tags: pdf, swisscomdev, appcloud

I'm want to create a PDF-file inside a NodeJS server-application  (or at least fill inputs in a PDF-file). 
I found several solutions on google but am not sure if the Swisscom Application Cloud will allow me to run those modules, generate PDF's and save them.
Is it possible to run any NodeJS module?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correct. Swisscom Application Cloud is a certified Cloud Foundry platform without any known limitations using the NodeJS buildpack. You can bundle any NPM module. You can choose if you wish to use latest buildpack from GitHub or the Swisscom provided (see it with `cf buildpacks`).

Have a look at the docs [Node.js Buildpack](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/index.html) and on GitHub [nodejs-buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack)

> **Vendor App Dependencies**
>
> To vendor dependencies for an app using the
>   Node.js buildpack, run npm install from your app directory. This
>   command vendors dependencies into the node_modules directory of your
>   app directory.

For example, the following example vendors dependencies into the `my-nodejs-app/node_modules` directory:

```
$ cd my-nodejs-app
$ npm install
```

The `cf push` command uploads the vendored dependencies with the app.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, go ahead. This is a very common task. Just make sure to save the generated PDFs outside of the app container if you need to keep them, as the app's local storage is ephemeral. The best solution for this is S3 in most cases.

Comment: so, you're saying that node-modules like pdffiller (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdffiller), which require the PDFtk (https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) will work?

Comment: @dosbenzos The latter seems to be a (graphical) Windows application, so no, that won't work. But you can probably use PDFtk Server if you build a statically linked Linux binary and ship that with your app.